# multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array(
    array(
      'id' => 1,
      'sht' => 'L',
      'tm' => 'tttt'
    ),
   array(
      'id' => 7,
      'tm' => 'xyz'
    ),
   array(
       'id' => 12,
       'hand' => 'R'
   ),
   array(
     'id' => 20
   )
);

$id = array_column($array, "id");
//Getting this result
 Array
 (
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 7
   [2] => 12
   [3] => 20
 )
```

//Expecting like this

```
Array (
 [id] => Array (
     [H] => 1
     [S] => 7
     [F] => 12
     [G] => 20
 ),
[sht] => Array (
     [H] => L
     [S] => ''
     [F] => ''
     [G] => ''
 )
[tm] => Array (
     [H] => tttt
     [S] => xyz
     [F] => ''
     [G] => ''
 )
[hand] => Array (
     [H] => ''
     [S] => ''
     [F] => R
     [G] => ''
 )
)
```

I do not wish you keep indexing like 0,1,2,3 i want to put indexing like H,S,F,G how can i put it the same into my query please suggest

Also explain how key behave how can we set our defined key instead 0,1

Comment: you'll have to make an associative array.

Comment: The basic tutorials should explain how associative arrays work, also, what have you tried in order to get your desired array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2khEvD)

check this code

```
$array = array(
    array(
      'id' => 1,
      'sht' => 'L',
      'tm' => 'tttt'
    ),
   array(
      'id' => 7,
      'tm' => 'xyz'
    ),
   array(
       'id' => 12,
       'hand' => 'R'
   ),
   array(
     'id' => 20
   )
);
$newKey=array("H","S","F","G");
//Get Key list
$keyList=array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
        if(!in_array($key2,$keyList))
            $keyList[]=$key2;
    }
}
//===========

$result=array();
$i=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    //add '' if key does not exist
    foreach($keyList as $k){     
        if(!array_key_exists($k,$value))
            $value[$k]='';
    }
    //=============================
    //add to new array with letter key($newkey)
    foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
        $result[$key2][$newKey[$i]]=$value2;                         
    }
    //=========================================
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: if we have Array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sht] => R
            [tm_name] => xyz
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [tm_name] => xyz
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [hand] => L
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
        )

)

Comment: and expecting like 
Array
(
    [H] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sht] => R
            [tm_name] => xyz
        )

    [S] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [tm_name] => xyz
        )

    [L] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [hand] => L
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
        )

)

Comment: than what to do please suggest

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!